# Build Data access layer from scratch vs Auto generated Data access layer by Visual studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, data-access-layer

I've build Windows Form and I have some question.

I wonder why we have to build data access layer from scratch despite visual studio can generated code for do that.

What are the advantage/disadvantage of both ?

What is the situation that each solution should use?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different options available to a developer that needs to add a data access layer (DAL) to their application.  I'm going to assume here that when you say "Visual studio can generate code for that", you are referring to Microsoft's Entity Framework (EF), which you can use to generate business objects and repositories from a schema (and vice versa).  There are other ways that VS could be used to generate your data access layer (e.g. using T4 templates and code generation).  Some of the factors that come into play when considering whether to roll your own data access layer include:

- Time. Probably the biggest factor (in my opinion). There are plenty of references available to learn the conventions required to get up and running with an EF data layer in very little time in deed.  This is an extremely fast route to take to get data into your application.  Past simply loading and saving data from a persistence store, existing frameworks such as EF make it easy to quickly support things like transactions and caching.  If write your own DAL, it will probably take longer to get data out of a data store, and it will certainly take longer to test it to the same degree that EF is proven.
- Features. You get A LOT of features 'out of the box' with EF.  It will take a while to add these to your DAL.
- Experience. There are plenty of pitfalls when writing your own DA layer from scratch - why re-invent the wheel?  Writing a good DAL from the ground up takes some coding experience to do well (but is a great learning experience and a very satisfying project to work on)
- Control. You may prefer to write your own DAL if you prefer to be in control of every aspect of the code.  Whilst a framework like EF can be configured in many ways, and will work for many applications, particular simple ones, the more complex requirements of a large application (be it computationally complex or with a particular performance profile) may be better suited to the more tweakable custom DAL.  For example, you might not like the SQL generated by EF, or you don't like the way that child models are loaded.  There are plenty of open source DALs which provide a solid foundation to build on, making it easy to hook into any aspect of the DAL.
- Existence of Legacy Code. In some extreme cases, if you working within an exiting application and you need to meet existing interface requirements, or fit with existing patterns of data loading, you may find it easier to generate your own DA layer.  The preferable alternative here would be to write an adapter layer to adapt your DAL to the existing application requirements, thereby decoupling your DA layer from legacy code requirements.

If you do plan to write your own DAL, I'd certainly recommend looking taking a look at code generation options that exist.  Plan for your schema to change frequently, and be able to regenerate your custom DAL quickly.  Tools like Code Smith, MyGeneration and the T4 templating tools in VS can be a great assistance when writing a DAL from scratch.